# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 10: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using **python 3.7** and was trying to import a *dataset (csv)* using **PANDAS**
When i execute the following code, i get an error which says

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 10: invalid start
>   byte

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv('food.csv')
```

The same thing works when i try the following-

```
import csv
rows = []

with open('ABBREV.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the encoding of the file:

```
with open('food.csv') as f:
    print(f)
```

Then use that encoding for opening the CSV

`dataset = pd.read_csv('food.csv', encoding = ???)`

[Pandas read_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)